# Como atribuir os elementos de uma lista a diferentes variáveis em Python?

Tags: python, lista, python-2.7, variáveis

Tenho uma lista, como a seguinte:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Mesmo sem saber quantos elementos tem dentro da lista, como faço para atribuir cada elemento da lista a uma variável distinta? (como no exemplo abaixo)

```
elemen1 = '1'
elemen2 = '2'
elemen3 = '3'
elemen4 = '4'
elemen5 = '5'
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Isto?

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a, b, c, d, e = lista
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8LTOmg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wvfcbocw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/ListToTuple.py).

É possível fazer com o mecanismo de tuplas, onde você pode definir variáveis em sequência e a lista fará a população delas automaticamente. Claro, precisa bater o número de elementos com a de variáveis, caso contrário ou alguns elementos não entrarão nas variáveis ou algumas variáveis ficarão sem valor.

Quase sempre isso não faz sentido e não traz vantagens. Uma variável acessada pelo seu índice não deixa de ser uma variável. Especialmente uma variável com o mesmo nome diferenciado apenas um número sequencial mostra que é a opção errada. Em bem poucos casos onde uma API funciona de um jeito e há muita vantagem em outra forma é que deveria fazer isso.

Comment: O código citado não funcionaria, pois quero fazer sem saber quantos elementos tem na lista

Comment: Aí você quer o impossível (dentro da normalidade) ou ou completamente desnecessário, conforme eu citei. Na verdade respondi para indicar a curiosidade, com este comentário fica claro que deseja fazer algo sem sentido. Até é possível usar reflexão, mas aí faz menso sentido ainda, porque a única justificativa para fazer isto é uma possível ínfima melhoria de performance, que depende inclusive de implementação e poderia nem ocorrer. Com reflexão ficará bem mais lento sempre, então acabaria a única motivação hipostética. E ainda não teria sentido acessar variáveis que nem sabe se existem ou não

Comment: Entendi. Desculpe se ofendi. É pouco conhecimento no tema. Eu poderia acessar os elementos da lista pelo índice, ainda assim, quero fazer um código que, neste novo caso, conte a quantidade de elementos da lista, e faça o pipeline seguinte para cada elemento da lista. Ou seja, não quero ter que saber quantos elementos tem na lista, para posteriormente executar as funções para cada um deles.

Comment: Não ofendeu, nem imagino como poderia. O que você quer de fato é outra coisa e fica mais claro que não precisa de variáveis isoladas, quer só acessar a lista. Eu respondi o que perguntou, que serve quase que apenas como curiosidade de como funciona.

Comment: @BrunoSantos Para "executar funções em cada elemento" você usa um `for` e não precisa de variaveis soltas. Algo como `for elemento in lista: funcao(elemento)`. No fim está a provar exatamente o que o Maniero disse, que o seu exemplo não é o que você quer e as variaveis soltas não ajudam só desajudam.