# Como criar uma lista de objetos de tamanho variável, e atribuir seus atributos sem listá-los um a um?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, classes

Preciso ler um arquivo e passar suas informações para uma lista de objetos. O arquivo é no formato:

"atributo1", "atributo2", "atributo3", ...,"atributoN"

cada linha contém as informações de um objeto diferente. Todos os objetos são da mesma classe.

Como eu crio um objeto para associar seus valores se eu não sei quantas linhas o arquivo pode ter? Não quero ter que declarar N objetos, tem como fazer iterativamente?

A mesma coisa com os atributos, não quero fazer:

```
 objeto.a1 = xxx

 objeto.a2 = xxx

 .

 .

 .

 objeto.aM= xxx
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Isso parece ser o mesmo problema abordado em [Como atribuir os elementos de uma lista a diferentes variáveis em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/346410/101).

Quando você estuda todos os mecanismos da linguagem antes de começar a criar programas que sejam mais úteis que exercício isolado, descobre que Python tem um mecanismo chamado lista. Ele é um vetor (*array*) até um pouco mais flexível. Este tip ode estrutura de dados serve para colocar vários valores sob a mesma variável, assim não precisa criar uma infinidade delas, não precisa saber quantas precisa (em algumas linguagens o *array* básico tem que saber o tamanho logo antes de inicializá-lo, Python já tem um mecanismo que permite ele crescer se necessário).

Quando usa um *array* ou uma lista, que é parecido com uma matriz que deve ter aprendido na escola, você acessa cada elemento por um índice, seria esse número que você está usando nos nomes das variáveis, porém, ele ficar de forma isolado e pode ser usado até uma variável dentro dele, o que dá muita flexibilidade.

Vou usar o nome que usou, mas seria melhor usar nomes mais significativos:

```
objeto.a[1]
objeto.a[2]
.
.
.
objeto.a[N]
```

Um código aproximado do que precisa fazer para adicionar no laço que lê o arquivo seria:

```
lista.append(Obj())
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/VariableSize.py).

Sendo que `Obj` seria essa classe que criou um objeto lendo um dado do arquivo.

Comment: Entendi a resposta para a lista, mas a minha segunda pergunta e mais sobre se é possível eu criar uma lista de ponteiro para cada atributo da minha classe.

Comment: Pyhon não tem ponteiros.