# É possível criar variáveis a partir de um contador?

Tags: python

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber se é possível a partir do valor obtido em um contador, criar variáveis na mesma quantidade. Para ilustrar melhor:

contador_pessoas = 2

peso_pessoa1 = float(input('Insira seu peso em KG: '))

altura_pessoa1 = float(input('Insira sua altura em CM: '))

peso_pessoa2 = float(input('Insira seu peso em KG: '))

altura_pessoa2 = float(input('Insira sua altura em CM: '))

Escrevi manualmente as variáveis peso_pessoa1, peso_pessoa2, altura_pessoa1 e altura_pessoa2.
Contudo se estivesse tratando de 100 pessoas, por exemplo, se tornaria impraticável. Então surgiu minha dúvida, se através de algum código eu consiga fazer algo parecido. Sou iniciante em programação, talvez seja algo simples que eu ainda não conheça.

Comment: Use listas, na linha de

    peso_pessoas = []; 
    peso_pessoas.append(float(input('insira seu peso...'))

Comment: Ainda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/346439/101.